# Как ограничить движение камеры?

Tags: unity3d

Привет. Игрок двигается по кругу, дочерним объектом к нему подключена камера с таким скриптом -

```
public float Smoothness = 0.3F;
public Vector2 Sensitivity = new Vector2(4, 4);
public Vector2 LimitX = new Vector2(-70, 80);

public Vector2 LimitY = new Vector2(-70, 80);

private Vector2 NewCoord;
public Vector2 CurrentCoord;
private Vector2 vel;

void Update()
{
    NewCoord.x = Mathf.Clamp(NewCoord.x, LimitX.x, LimitX.y);
    NewCoord.y = Mathf.Clamp(NewCoord.y, LimitY.x, LimitY.y);
    NewCoord.x -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * Sensitivity.x;
    NewCoord.y += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * Sensitivity.y;
    CurrentCoord.x = Mathf.SmoothDamp(CurrentCoord.x, NewCoord.x, ref vel.x, Smoothness / 2);
    CurrentCoord.y = Mathf.SmoothDamp(CurrentCoord.y, NewCoord.y, ref vel.y, Smoothness / 2);
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(CurrentCoord.x, CurrentCoord.y, 0);
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Зеленые линии - это лимит движения камеры по X. Вращение камеры не как не влияет на лимит. Вообще мне нужно чтобы камера смотрела в центр и у нем был лимит по X от -50 до + 50, например. Я могу установить эти лимиты и все будет как надо пока камера не повернет. Как сделать чтобы ограничения вращения были, всегда, направленны в центр?

Comment: А у вас игрок, который движется по кругу поворачивается или (как на верхних картинках) на запад смотрит всегда?

Comment: Поворачивается.